# How do I change the scope a method is executed in in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Because angular has no native drag and drop support I'm writing a directive that makes different drag events work in an angular way.

I'm doing this by creating a custom attribute that will bind and execute my event handler.

### Directive containing the element with custom dragstart handler

Here's the template that I want to put the my `customDragStartHandler` attribute-directive into:

```
myApp.directive("myDraggableList", function() {
  return {
    template: '<ul> <li ng-repeat = "item in listItems" 
                    draggable = "true" 
                    customDragStartHandler = "handleDragStart"> 
                      {{item.label}} 
                    </li> 
              </ul>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.handleDragStart = function(event) {
        // handle dragstart event
      }
    }
  }
})
```

### Custom dragstart event directive

```
myApp.directive("customDragStartHandler", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      "customDragStartHandler": "&"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('dragstart', function(event) {
        scope.customDragStartHandler( {event: event} )
      })
    }
  }
})
```

## The problem: the handler isn't called in the scope of the link function

Under normal circumstances I expect and want an event handler to be called in the scope of the link function. i.e. if there is a variable in the link function then I expect it to be available in the scope of the handler.

Let's add an illustrative variable, `mySetupVariable` to the link function to show this:

```
myApp.directive("myDraggableList", function() {
  return {
    template: '<ul> <li ng-repeat = "item in listItems" 
                    draggable = "true" 
                    customDragStartHandler = "handleDragStart"> 
                      {{item.label}} 
                    </li> 
              </ul>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var mySetupVariable = 'a string I want to reference'

      scope.handleDragStart = function(event) {
        // I expect to be able to access mySetupVariable here
        // but instead the scope is empty and `.this` represents
        // the scope of the template
        // 
        console.log mySetupVariable // => undefined
        console.log this.scope      // => scope of template
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The problem is that I can't. The handleDrag function is called in the scope of the template, not the linking function.

How can I make the handler execute in the scope of the link function rather than the template?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind()` for that

```
  scope.handleDragStart = function(event) {
    // I expect to be able to access mySetupVariable here
    // but instead the scope is empty and `.this` represents
    // the scope of the template
    // 
    console.log mySetupVariable // => undefined
    console.log this.scope      // => scope of template
  }.bind(this)
```

Comment: So I tried this and it does move `this` to being the link function which is great. However It doesn't seem to respect the normal closure effect of the link function and `mySetupVariable` is no longer available. Neither are the normal `scope`, `element` and `attrs` variables. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: You can also use `var linkSelf = this;` within the `link` function, and then refer to `linkSelf.mySetupVariable`. See also https://gist.github.com/jashmenn/b306add36d3e6f0f6483